# Leave random effects out when correlated with fixed effects?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, glmm

Is it appropriate (or not) to leave a random intercept out of a model if the random intercept acts as a proxy for multiple fixed effects that are being included in the model?

I have been given data on animals that have been sampled at six time points throughout a single year. The researcher who collected the data is interested to look at how rainfall, temperature, presence of pouch young, presence of lactation and antioxident levels impact on the animals body condition. I am using a GLMM to model this data.

Technically, time of sampling should be included in the model as a random intercept as observations at the animal level are clustered within sampling time. However, the sampling time would be expected to be associated with several variables for which we are interested in their effect on animal body condition. For example, rainfall, temperature and variables associated with reproduction would all be expected to be seasonal to some degree and hence associated with time of sampling. I have demonstrated this for some pairs of variables, with Pearson correlation coefficients ranging from 0.4-0.65. In this case I am unsure if including time of sampling as a random intercept is a good idea and should be done, or if it is a bad idea and will potentially mask the effects of other variables that are associated with sampling time? Is it appropriate, or not, in this case to leave the random intercept - sampling time - out of our models when variables of interest are likely to be associated with sampling time?